# Hadoop 2.2.0 Configuration deprecation

Tags: java, hadoop

I set up the Hadoop 2.2.0 Cluster and now running my java client to process data. After running my java program, I notice the output displays like this:

```
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar 
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.combine.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.combine.class
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.textoutputformat.separator is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class 
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
```

The module is working well and looks like that doesn't affect anything. But how can I avoid this info messages? (I import maven hadoop-client 2.2.0 and use Job job = new Job())

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed in Hadoop 2.3, please refer: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10178

Answer (score 0):

Most are because of the Hadoop API change - all of the "mapred" package are moved to "mapreduce". You can change where you import "org.apache.hadoop.mapred" to "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce" to avoid such information. You could do similar change for some other messages such as

```
13/11/18 11:44:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
```

Comment: Yes, I uses the new API "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce" in my program but still gets the info messages...

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated means that these APIs are still there but they will be removed in future releases. The mapred namespace is old and the new mapreduce namespace has been added to replace it.

As the info messages and Zhutoulala mentioned  if you want to avoid these you need to use the new API instead of the old one. The new API is `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce`. By the way, the "new" API is there since 2009. You can see [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/sh1mmer/upgrading-to-the-new-map-reduce-api) for the changes

Comment: Actually, I have used the new API "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce" in my program, but it still shows these info messages...I don't why

Comment: This is because in Hadoop 2 the API has gone through more changes

Comment: Ok, so after importing new API, what should I do next to avoid this info megs?

Comment: follow the instructions :) you can add your current code to the question and I or someone else here will help amending it

Comment: I have checked the presentation you link above and I have used all the new API which is indicated in that link. No old API at all. But I still get the weird info msgs...

Comment: I initially thought you used the old API - the presentation (from 2009) shows the differences at that time. in Hadoop 2 there have been significant changes to how map/reduce works (it is now running on YARN) and with that additional changes in the new API were made. The old "new" API is still there but it is declared deprecated (i.e. will be removed in future versions). You can use it as is for now but it is recommended to update to the new changes as the warnings instruct

Comment: Ok. As you mentioned above, if I want to avoid these I need to use the new API instead of the old one which is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce. And now I use the new API but still get these info msgs. So I don't know how to update it.

Comment: where you use user.name use job.user.name instead etc.

Comment: Arnon, I don't think you get it.  He _isn't_ using job.user.name.  I'm getting the same error and also don't use it.  I'm guessing (wild guess) that this may be a maven problem?  I'm using Maven to package this up and get a list of things that are deprecated...that I don't use. 

I use:
"        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(config, "WordJob");
"

to set up the job...might this be the problem?