# Exact steps to kill Hadoop 2.2.0 Configuration deprecation info messages

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

This question is similar to [Hadoop 2.2.0 Configuration deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055482/hadoop-2-2-0-configuration-deprecation), but the answers to that question did not resolve the issue, so I am asking for specific steps in this question, and providing a specific example.

Consider the following short Map-only program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;


public class Foo {

    //     KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT
    public static class Map extends  Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job job = Job.getInstance();
        job.setJarByClass(Foo.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);
    }
}
```

When this code is run against the input:

```
The big brown cat went down the lazy road.
```

Using the command line below, assuming that the `Input` contains the input above.

```
hadoop jar Foo.jar Foo Input Output
```

The following messages will appear:

```
  4/01/19 18:37:36 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/01/19 18:37:37 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.mapoutput.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.value.class
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.inputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.inputformat.class
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.outputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.outputformat.class
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.mapoutput.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.key.class
14/01/19 18:37:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
```

The example above uses only `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce`, and I used the powerpoint that was linked to create it.

**What exactly needs to be changed (either in this code or in `/etc/hadoop`) to make the deprecation messages go away?**

Comment: I've been looking at this exact error. My analysis is that the Configuration class itself is using deprecated packages. In other words, it's not your fault, it's Hadoop's fault. Which is often the case.

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed in later version of Apache Hadoop - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10178

You can just upgrade your Apache Hadoop cluster or apply patches and re-build it.